# How to construct 4-regular graphs with few Hamiltonian decompositions?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-graphs, regular-graph

A [*Hamiltonian decomposition*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_decomposition#Number_of_decompositions) of a finite simple graph is a partition of its edge set so that each partition class forms a Hamiltonian cycle. This is only possible if the graph is $2k$-regular.

Interestingly, if a 4-regular graph has a Hamiltonian decomposition then it has at least four of them (stated [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_decomposition#Number_of_decompositions)). In my experience however, a "generic" 4-regular graph with a Hamiltonian decomposition has *many* more than four such decompositions.

> **Question 1:** How to generate or construct many 4-regular graphs with *exactly* four Hamiltonian decompositions? For a start, a few examples would help as well.
>
> **Question 2:** Are there any related results that provide (better) lower bounds on the number of Hamiltonian decompositions of 4-regular graphs?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X08006341) for each integer $n\geq3$ multigraphs of order $n$ with exactly four hamiltonian pairs are constructed.
Moreover, in section 6 the following conjecture is formulated.
16 is the smallest value among nonzero numbers of hamiltonian pairs in 4-regular simple graphs of any order.

Comment: @kabenyuk, your comment is missing $\ge 15$ at the end.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Yes, you are correct. The conjecture reads as follows: 
 16 is the smallest value among nonzero numbers of hamiltonian pairs in 4-regular simple graphs of any order $\geq15$. Thank you.